# Is there a way to put formatted maths into XML commenting C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-comments, comments

I want to be able to put a formatted mathematic equation into my XML comments, is there a plugin to allow me to do this or maybe some other way?

I am currently using this:

```
/// <summary>
/// e^-x/(1+e^-x)^2
/// </summary>
public double Sigmoid(x) => 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x));
```

But this doesn't seem like a very good solution.

I appreciate any answers.

Comment: [MathML](https://www.w3.org/Math/whatIsMathML.html) might work, but you would need to post-process the documentation output somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a native solution, but you can use an extension like [VsTeXCommentsExtension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1305558.VsTeXCommentsExtension) or [TeXcomments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pierreMertz.TeXcomments).